# Can't convert base64Image to ImageData object

Tags: javascript, base64, imagedata

I'm currently trying to convert a base64Encoded string (representation of an image) into an ImageData object in Javascript. However, this comes back with an  error:

Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to construct 'ImageData': The input data length is not a multiple of 4.

The encoded image is 940 x 740

What am I missing? Any help appreciated

[JSFiddle link with full code](https://jsfiddle.net/w7u2ba3c/)

```
   function _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
        var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
        var len = binary_string.length;
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return bytes.buffer;
    }


const base64String = ""; //truncated because stackoverflow question too long.
const arrBuffer = _base64ToArrayBuffer (base64String );

var array = new Uint8ClampedArray(arrBuffer);
console.log(array);
var image = new ImageData(array, 900, 740);
console.log(image);
```

Comment: You are passing png binary data to `ImageData` that is not the type of data it expects. It is expecting an array containing RGBA (red,green,blue,alpha) values, eg `[255,0,0,1, 0,255,0,1]` which would represent a red pixel and a green pixel.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I see. So the determining of what those potential values would be isn't really possibly without using canvas methods I assume? Goal here is to determine pixel colour values from base64 string.

Comment: You could determine them without the canvas, but that would require you to create the code to parse the png file format, or use an existing js library that does it. But that is way more overhead then just using the few lines it would take when using the canvas

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ImageData from a Canvas

```
function _base64ToImageData(buffer, width, height) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    var image = new Image();
    image.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
      var canvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvasElement.width = width;
      canvasElement.height = height;
      var context = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
      context.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0, width, height);
      resolve(context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height));
    });
    image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + buffer;
    document.body.appendChild(image);
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.body.removeChild(image);
    }, 1);
  });
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  _base64ToImageData(base64String, 2056, 1236).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```